# Nested Looping in php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have nested for each loop and getting the duplicates from that loop.I have added the result and actual result.

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = [[6,7],[8,9]];

foreach($a as $aitem)
{
   foreach($b as $bitem)
   {
      $bitems[]=$bitem;
   }
    $result[] = ["items"=>$aitem,
                 "subitems"=>$bitems] ;    
}

Result :
[{"items":1,"subitems":[6,7]},{"items":2,"subitems":[6,7,6,7]},{"items":3,"subitems":[6,7,6,7,6,7]}]

Actual Result
[{"items":1,"subitems":[6,7]},{"items":2,"subitems":[6,7]},{"items":3,"subitems":[6,7]}]

?>
```

Comment: Remove the `foreach` on `$b` and change `$result[] = ["items"=>$aitem,
                 "subitems"=>$b] ;`?

Comment: Empty the `$bitems` variable before each new subloop

Answer (score 0):

**Remove the foreach from loop that is cuasing the loop to repeat add the [0] to $b for getting the first item from b array**

```
<?php
$a = [1,2,3];
$b = [[6,7],[8,9]];

foreach($a as $aitem)
{

    $result[] = ["items"=>$aitem, "subitems"=>$b[0]] ;    
}
```